# How to pass the parameter into find_element in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Currently, I am practicing the utilization of Selenium for website testing. However, I have encountered an issue wherein I am unable to pass a parameter to a def function.

```
from booking.booking import Booking
    with Booking() as test:

    test.change_currency(currency='USD')`
```

```
def change_currency(self, currency=None):

    currency_element = self.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="b2indexPage"]/div[1]/div/header/nav[1]/div[2]/span[1]/button')
    currency_element.click()

    selected_currency_element = self.find_element(By.?, '?')
    selected_currency_element.click()
```

And here is the website that I try to test: https://www.booking.com/

[Image of inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccCQC.png)

I have try various ways by using By.CSS and By.XPATH methods.

Comment: What variable do you need to pass?

Comment: I suggest using `By.CSS_SELECTOR` and creating a css selector that locates the text inside an element using the value of `currency`.

Comment: Alternitavely use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` and `".ea1163d21f"` (this is one of the classes on the `<div>`. Then iterate through the elements returned to find the one with the currency as its text.

Comment: Side note...will this function work if no value is passed for `currency` and its default value is `None`? If the answer is no, then you shouldn't use a default value for the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing and testing with different currencies on `booking.com` easily with my implementation below:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

def change_currency(currency):
    currency_list = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="All currencies"]').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')

    for curr in currency_list:
        code = curr.text.split('\n')[1]
        if code == currency:
            curr.click()
            return True

driver = Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.booking.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# wait and click to open the "Select your currency" pop-up
currency_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="header-currency-picker-trigger"]')))
currency_button.click()

# wait and click to close the sign-in pop-up
sign_in = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Dismiss sign-in info."]')))
sign_in.click()

# change the currency to Thai Baht
change_currency('THB')
time.sleep(5)
```

As you can see the function `change_currency('THB')` changes the currency to `Thai Baht`. Similarly, you can do this for multiple currencies by calling this function from a loop of currencies.